# Возможно ли проигрывать модель в AR Core на 60 fps?

Tags: android

У гугл есть вот такой офф пример

https://github.com/google-ar/arcore-android-sdk/tree/master/samples/hello_ar_java

я проверил и он проигрывает модель со скоростью 30fps

Я так понимаю, что при использовании AR Core 30 fps это максимальная скорость, но с другой стороны никакого официального подтвердения этому я не нашел. Чтоб было написано

> AR Core максимальная скорость 30

Правильно ли я понимаю, что все же 30 это максимум?

**Правка**

Я так же нашел вот это

https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/c/camera-configs

и судя по вот этой настройке `ArCameraConfigFilter_setTargetFps(AR_CAMERA_CONFIG_TARGET_FPS_30);` можно сказать, что все таки 30 fps это его максимальная скорость

Comment: По моему отрисовкой модели занимается GLES а у него частота может быть изменена. Но это, как говорится, не точно )

Comment: @AndrewGrow да, он отприсовывает модели, но по сигналу из колбека `onDrawFrame()` или как то так он называется... Так вот я так понял, что этот метод вызывается системой со скоростью 30fps

Comment: Я не очень знаком с опен-гл, но может у него есть что нибудь вроде setFrameFrequency(60) ?

Comment: @AndrewGrow я не помню почему, но это не работает. Помоему это настройка для камеры, но когда она работает с AR Core то она не может давать больше 30. Как то так было... Только вот не могу найти ни подтверждающую инфу ни опровергающую